# Finding reason for removal of the logarithm in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, initial-value-problems, homogeneous-equation

I'm given an ODE
$$y' = \frac{x + 2y + 1}{2x + 3},~y(5/2) = 1/4.$$
To solve this I'm doing the following:

1. Solve system of equations
   $$2x_0 + 2y_0 = 1,$$
   $$2x_0  = 3,$$
   this gives me solutions $x_0 = \frac{3}{2}$, $y_0 = -\frac{1}{4}$. Then, I'm transforming variables $s = x + \frac{3}{2}$, $t = y - \frac{1}{4}$.
2. Transform the ODE using those new variables to the form
   $$t' = \frac{s + 2t}{2s}$$
   and using substitution of the form $t = s\cdot u(s)$ the equation is reduced to the
   $$u' = \frac{1}{2s} \implies u' = \frac{1}{2}\ln|C\cdot s|.$$
   Using initial conditions constant C can be found using $y(5/2) = 1/4$, $s(5/2) = 4$, $t(4) = 0$, $u(4) = 0$, hence $0 = \ln|4C| \implies C = \pm \frac{1}{4}$.
3. Putting it all together yields me
   $$y = \frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{3}{2}\right)\ln\left|\frac{x + 3/2}{4}\right| + 1/4$$
   with two domains $I_1 = (-3/2, +\infty)$ and $I_2 = (-\infty, -3/2)$.
   But my textbook states that the answer is 
   $$y = \frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{3}{2}\right)\ln\frac{x + 3/2}{4} + 1/4,~I = (-3/2, +\infty)$$

Hence the following two questions:

1. What was the reason for removal of absolute value in the logarithm?
2. Why is mine domain of validity wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the initial condition is given for $x=\frac52$ we are assuming the solution for the domain $x>-\frac32\implies \frac{x + 3/2}{4}>0$.